# Django admin raw_id_field not working as expected

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and trying out djangoAdmin and i am stuck at one problem. i am using raw_id_field for a column and i am not getting the magnifying glass icon but during edit respective company name shows up next to the field. I know it has something to do with the relations.

in the below code how do i say

**`company_master.p_company_id HAS_ONE company_images.p_company_id`**

Model.py

```
from django.db import models  

class CompanyMaster(models.Model):
    p_company_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key= True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "company_master"


class CompanyImage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    p_company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyMaster)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "company_images"
```

Admin.py

```
class CompanyImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']
    raw_id_fields = ("p_company",)

admin.site.register(CompanyImage, CompanyImageAdmin)
```

Comment: I think you need to add `CompanyMaster` to the admin too: `admin.site.register(CompanyMaster)` so that it can be added.

Comment: pls give this as the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by **Timmy O'Mahony**

```
admin.site.register(CompanyMaster)
```

Did the trick